# Singular or plural verb after a list with multiple "every"s?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, compound-subjects

Which sentence is correct?

1. Every apple, every orange, and every pear ***is*** good for you.
2. Every apple, every orange, and every pear ***are*** good for you.

Comment: There seems to be a conflict of two rules here ('every' takes the singular; coordinated subjects take the plural). [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man+and+every+woman+is%2Cman+and+every+woman+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cman%20and%20every%20woman%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cman%20and%20every%20woman%20are%3B%2Cc0) suggest that 'every man and every woman is' is the preferred usage, but that 'every man and every woman were' is not unknown....

Comment: I'd say that the proximity principle strongly encourages the choice of the singular verb form.

Comment: @Peter I wouldn't use it, but this _is_ a dodgy area. _Most women, and every man_ ...? // The Google Ngram results seem particularly untrustworthy here.

Comment: This is the correct answer and its explanation is accurate..

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In "X is/are good for you", I think that the critical issue regarding numerical agreement is whether *X* presents a singular or plural 'thing' to the rest of the sentence. In this case, the sense is that "*every apple, every orange, and every pear*" presents a singular item (any *one* instance of any of those named fruit types), so singular agreement applies. The alternate interpretation - that multiple fruit are presented at once - doesn't work in this sentence. I suspect that the numerical-agreement rules regarding *every* and *and* are something of a red herring here.

Comment: @Lawrence I can't think of a single example where I'd not find 'were' unnatural-sounding. ?/*_Every man and every dog were photographed_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hm, you have a point there. Even so, I don’t see the tension between *every* and *and* in relation to numerical agreement, except in the context of a theoretical exercise. But why? That’s the intriguing question. Any concrete ‘evaluation’ of the ‘triple-every’ part produces a singular noun. My suggestion is that the noun phrase as a whole is therefore also singular. (By the way, I pinged you because I was interested in your thoughts on that hypothesis.)

Answer (score 4):

Every is singular--even when there are many everys.

Although the simple answer above was down-voted by someone, consider the scope of quantification of *every* (or, for that matter, *each*):

Every (man, woman, and child) *is* invited.
Each (man, woman, and child) *is* invited.

Distributing the quantifier does not change the quantification or the arity of the verb:

Every man, every woman, and every child *is* invited.

Comment: It seems to be more complicated than that though.  ***The*** is also singular: (The car is blue) and it can be either distributed or not: *The car and the truck* -> *The car and truck* but these both take plural:  The car and the truck are blue.

Comment: A good answer on ELU needs supporting evidence, from a respected grammar say.